# Get friday from week number and year in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have week number and year, need to find out date (friday) in that week and year.

```
function getFriday(week_num, year)
{
    ?

    return friday_date_object;
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Surely getDay(day_num, week_num, year) would be more useful?

Comment: "You need to convert that to Friday of that particular week"? - Please reword your question - it is hard to tell what you are asking for exactly.

Comment: @Jim day_num is always 5 (friday), your function will return same result, yes

Comment: @JM4 He means that if we call getFriday(2,2011) it will return a date object of the 2nd Friday in 2011 (14th Jan 2011)

Comment: @JM4 reworded my question a bit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The week #1 is the week with the first Thursday.

Here is a function to get any day:

```
var w2date = function(year, wn, dayNb){
    var j10 = new Date( year,0,10,12,0,0),
        j4 = new Date( year,0,4,12,0,0),
        mon1 = j4.getTime() - j10.getDay() * 86400000;
    return new Date(mon1 + ((wn - 1)  * 7  + dayNb) * 86400000);
};
console.log(w2date(2010, 1, 4));
```

week numbers start at 1 until 52 or 53 it depends the year.
For the day numbers, 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, ... and 4 is Friday

Answer (score 1):

Use the  [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library. It's great for all date-related functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some quick code

```
var DAY = 86400000;

function getFriday(weekNum, year) {
  var year = new Date(year.toString()); // toString first so it parses correctly year numbers
  var daysToFriday = (5 - year.getDay()); // Note that this can be also negative
  var fridayOfFirstWeek = new Date(year.getTime() + daysToFriday * DAY);
  var nthFriday = new Date(fridayOfFirstWeek.getTime() + (7 * (weekNum - 1) * DAY));
  return nthFriday;
}
```

Split some variables for readability.

But if you find yourself writing more complex time operations, you're better using a library instead.

Comment: new Date(2010) gives Thu Jan 01 1970 with Chrome

Comment: What is the DAY variable representing?

Comment: @Blake, the number of milliseconds in a day

Comment: @Mic: Oops. Yes, it tries to parse 2010 as the number of seconds, instead of year. `new Date(2010)` behaves differently than `new Date("2010")`. Changed code to reflect that, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0):

i think if i should not use any date library i would:

assuming u use a christian week, where sunday is the frist day of the week. this is neccessary to find out if the first days in a year belong to the first week of the year or not.

create an array. months = new Array(31,28,31, ... )
if(year % 4 == 0) then february has 29 days.

days = num_week * 7;

then iterate over the month and decrease days by month[current]. if days gets negative increase days with the current month days again.

result: year-(current+1)-days

i hope this helps you. what u have to add on your own is the handling for january and the first days.

Comment: leap year is calculated like this:
`((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0)`