# how can i get date based on week number and weekday and year in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

how can i get date based on week number and weekday and year in javascript?
If i give year is 2012 and weeknumber is 30 and day is monday(1) then how should i get date is 2012-07-23 in javascript?

Comment: It seems you may find useful information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555324/get-friday-from-week-number-and-year-in-javascript the accepted answer exposes a function that's exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You may date.js useful:

Latest code from here: http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js

Project page here: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/, note that I cannot find a link to the latest source from the project home page.