# how to get a javascript date from a week number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How i can get the date of the first day of a week from the week number and the year, in javascript (or jquery)?

example : week 30 , year 2013

thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630540/how-can-i-get-date-based-on-week-number-and-weekday-and-year-in-javascript)

Comment: You need to calculate that using Javascripts `Date` function.

Comment: Duplicate to this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580824/how-to-convert-a-week-number-to-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: yes you're right chirag, it's a duplicated question. sorry :x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript calculate date from week number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
var days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

d.setDate(d.getDate() + (week * 7));

console.log(days[d.getDay()]);
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/gXQk6/1/)

Comment: @Ishan Jain, Thanks for creating fiddle. I don't have permission to accept your edit due to my reputation. So added manually.

Answer (score 1):

Using ISO 8601 week numbering, you can start with the first week of the year and add `(n - 1) * 7` days to get the first day of the required week. E.g.

```js
function getDateByWeek(week, year) {

  // Create a date for 1 Jan in required year
  var d = new Date(year, 0);
  // Get day of week number, sun = 0, mon = 1, etc.
  var dayNum = d.getDay();
  // Get days to add
  var requiredDate = --week * 7;

  // For ISO week numbering
  // If 1 Jan is Friday to Sunday, go to next week 
  if (dayNum != 0 || dayNum > 4) {
    requiredDate += 7;
  }

  // Add required number of days
  d.setDate(1 - d.getDay() + ++requiredDate);
  return d;
}

// Week 44 of 2021 starts on Mon 1 Nov 2021
console.log(getDateByWeek(44,2021).toString());
```

If some other week numbering scheme is required, just adjust the starting date accordingly.

Comment: first line should read 'var d = new Date(year, 0, 1)' and it works

Comment: This is not correct: getDateByWeek(1, 2020) results in 2020-01-06 in local time, but first week of 2020 starts actually at 2019-12-30, because thursday is 2nd of january and in ISO 8601 thursday marks the first week - so monday of the first week is in december.