# Get Date given Year and Week in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given say 2013 and 38 (38 = 38th week of the year) I want to get 2013-09-16. Is there a Javascript or jQuery function?

Note: the week of year is based on ISO week day calendar. i. e. given 2014 and 1, I need to get 2013-12-30

Comment: what is `38` represent in your question? `16 + 9`..??

Comment: 38 is 38th week of year

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get friday from week number and year in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555324/get-friday-from-week-number-and-year-in-javascript)

Comment: @epascarello thanks - interesting title of that question :)

Comment: @epascarello and other close votes -- the answer in the suggested question does not apply because it does not fulfill the iso calendar requirement

Comment: With my Date settings on my computer, I get what you expected using that code... http://jsfiddle.net/s7pR6/ Are you complaining that it does not return the string "2013-12-30" exactly? You can format the date in any way you want.

Comment: @epascarello no i wasn't complaining about the format. i misunderstood the functionality of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer from here [Get friday from week number and year in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555559/1151831) you will get your excepted answer

```
var w2date = function(year, wn){
    var Day10 = new Date( year,0,10,12,0,0),
        Day4 = new Date( year,0,4,12,0,0),
        weekmSec = Day4.getTime() - Day10.getDay() * 86400000;  // 7 days in milli sec 
    return new Date(weekmSec + ((wn - 1)  * 7 ) * 86400000);   
};

w2date(year, week);
```

calculating total milli seconds of the given week count (`weekmSec + ((wn - 1)  * 7 ) * 86400000`)  and then passing it to Date object will give you the expected answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var year = 2013, weeks = 38;
var m = moment("01-01-" + year, "DD-MM-YYYY");
m.add('weeks', weeks - 1)
console.log(m.toDate())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vUjq7/)

Using js

```
var year = 2013, weeks = 38;
var d = new Date(year, 0, 1);
d.setDate((weeks - 1) * 7)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Gt23/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet of code:

```
var d = new Date("January 1, 2013 00:00:00");
d.setDate(259);
alert(d);
```

259 represents 37 weeks * 7.

Hope this helps

Comment: ISO weeks start on week that has the first Thursday of the year, so not necessarily 1 January.